# Sum of every row or every column of a rectangular grid is an even number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose that a rectangular grid is filled with 0's, 1's in each square such that for every row and every column, the numbers have an even sum. Prove that if the squares are colored black and white as on a chessboard, then the numbers on the black squares have an even sum.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Seems like a question better posed on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Call the rows r_1,r_2,...,r_n. Now do a transformation where the new r_(n-2) is the old r_(n-2) xored with the old r_n, and the new r_n is the old r_n xored with the old r_n. Verify that the new square satisfies all the conditions and moreover the parities of the sum of black squares as well as sum of white squares are maintained.

Now do the same with columns. Again verify everything. Since the last row and the last column now consists entirely of zeros we can delete them without changing any of the conditions or parities of the sums of black squares and white squares.

Hence we are done by induction if we can handle the base case, a 2x2 square.  I leave that as an exercise.

Added: The important thing to notice is that the xoring is always between two black squares or two white squares.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about this but I'm interested to see if I'm close.

Regardless of whether white = 0, or black = 1, then black will be even.

If black = 0, then sum of black squares = zero = even.

All rows and columns add up to an even sum.  If white is 0, then sum of black squares must be even because the row and columns of the black squares are even.

I think the only way this doesn't work is if white and black squares have the varying values (black can be randomly assigned 1 or 0 AND white can be randomly assigned 1 or 0).

Comment: it's random. black squares can be either 0 or 1, so does white squares.